# Why IE is caching data from same URI call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

Whenever I'm calling my service in asp.net mvc IE 9 is caching the previous data in it's browser so my new changes is not reflecting back in the code.
Please tell me how can I off this automatic caching from IE 9.

Please help me.

Comment: would this help? http://superuser.com/questions/461285/how-to-disable-caching-in-internet-explorer-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can pass one new parameter in your URI like timestamp which will make each call a unique url call so IE 9 will not cache it.
or if you are using Asp.net MVC then you can make changes in your global.asax file to switch of caching at browser level like this.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
           // HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, tokenId");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Making the change at the global.asax level may not be appropriate, because you might want caching for certain areas in the app. You can try disabling the caching at the page level using the @outputcache directive or setting the cache at the web.config level. Please checkout this URL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178606%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, but I think he is asking for disabling cache in IE 9 or any other browser.